# Channel End Notification exception is coming while using JMS with JBoss

Tags: java, jboss, jms, jboss7.x, hornetq

I am using JMS with JBoss. But whenever i run the my consumer code i always get the below exception

```
[org.jboss.as.naming] (Remoting "sorabh216901" task-2) JBAS011806: Channel end notification received, closing channel Channel ID 091878ba (inbound) of Remoting connection 007ce8a6 to /192.168.2.47:53318
```

My Consumer class is as below:

```
public class TopicConsumer implements MessageListener{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JMSException {
        Context context = TopicConsumer.getInitialContext();
        try{
        System.out.println("Entering into the main method!!!");

        TopicConnectionFactory connectionFactory = (TopicConnectionFactory) context.lookup("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
        Topic topic = (Topic) context.lookup("jms/topic/test");
        TopicConnection connection = connectionFactory.createTopicConnection("testuser", "testpassword");
        TopicSession session = connection.createTopicSession(true, TopicSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        session.createSubscriber(topic).setMessageListener(new TopicConsumer());
        connection.start();
        System.out.println("Exiting from the main method!!!");
        }finally{
            //context.close();
        }

    }

    public void onMessage(Message arg0) {
        System.out.println("Incoming Message : " + arg0);
    }


    public static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException{
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
        props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS", "JBOSS-LOCAL-USER");
        props.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", "false");
        props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
        props.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"remote://192.168.2.47:4447");


        props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
        // username
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
        // password
        props.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "testpassword");

        return new InitialContext(props);

    }
}
```

When ever i ran the code i get the successful handshake in logs i.e.

```
    INFO: EJBCLIENT000013: Successful version handshake completed for receiver context EJBReceiverContext{clientContext=org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientContext@cd0d2e, 
receiver=Remoting connection EJB receiver [connection=Remoting connection <1e03fce>,channel=jboss.ejb,nodename=sorabh216901]} on channel Channel ID 9823d1ac (outbound) of Remoting connection 004edf4a to /192.168.2.47:4447
```

But the program just closed and in server logs i get channel end notification.

Please suggest, what is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line at the end of main method of `TopConsumer`
 class:

```
try {
            Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This will not stop the JVM. And you won't get Channel End Notification exception

Comment: The answer is correct in the sense that it avoids the program end, however the "Channel End Notification" is not related to that problem: it simply means that the connection to the JNDI server has been closed, so it's not really an error.  Newer versions of JBoss (i.e. WildFly) log that message at debug level. See https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3201  and the source code of method handleEnd() at https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-remote-naming/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/naming/remote/protocol/v1/RemoteNamingStoreV1.java